Show all items which share a content type inside one list view
I have a site content type named Carrier, and we will be creating custom lists based on this site content type.. now how i can have a single list view which will show items from all the lists? with the ability to filter and sort items?
Thanks

SharePoint doesn't have an out-of-the-box way to create views for multiple lists.
As a workaround, you can try using Power Apps to add data from multiple lists and add custom search and filtering capabilities.
Reference: How to Display SharePoint List Items in PowerApps Gallery?

thanks for the reply, but if i use power apps, then i will need to manually modify it when we add or remove new custom lists.. am i correct? which will not be feasible, as we will be adding/removing custom lists frequently
